# What does boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator do?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm starting with boost asio programming in C++ and when looking over the examples I just can't understand what does `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator` do.

Code:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1]);
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
tcp::resolver::iterator end;

tcp::socket socket(io_service);
boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
while (error && endpoint_iterator != end)
{
  socket.close();
  socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
}
```

Please help me and excuse me if my question doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Gotta love the boost.asio namespaces. *barf*

Comment: FYI: the query is for a service only.  if you're looking for a specific host fpr a service, you need to add another parameter to the tcp::resolver::query ctor.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator` iterates through the address list of the host that you specified (hosts can have multiple addresses).

Like an std::string::iterator iterates through its characters, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterates through its address list.

The following code:

```
while (error && endpoint_iterator != end)
{
  socket.close();
  socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
}
```

is attempting to establish a connection to each endpoint until it succeeds or runs out of endpoints (thank you for the correction Eugen Constantin Dinca).

Comment: Actually the `while` tries to connect to each endpoint until it succeeds or it runs out of endpoints. So at most 1 endpoint will be connected at the end of the loop.

Comment: Why does it use *endpoint_iterator++ instead of endpoint_iterator++? Why would you need pointers?

Comment: @Hami `ip::tcp::resolver::iterator` is not a pointer, it just looks and behaves like one. The postfix increment operator (`operator++(int)`) gets the next iterator **after** the indirection operator (`operator*()`) obtains the underlying `endpoint` and returns it to `socket::connect()`. If the connection fails, `error` is set and the loop continues. These are the same concepts used by iterators in the Standard Template Library.

Comment: To clarify @SamMiller 's comment, the increment operator is applied **before** the indirection operator (due to operator precedence rules), but it is returning the original iterator to the indirection operator due to the fact that `++` is a postfix operator.

Comment: iterator is deprecated in the laster version of boost, is there an alternative to this?

Comment: @SrijanChaudhary  You can use the following
[function](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve/overload3.html)

  `auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);`